# syso shortcut isn't working in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, system.out

[image: Example:] so when I'm trying to use the shortcut syso in eclipse IDE it opens a suggestion pop up instead of just displaying System.out.println like it used to any suggestions to fix this? (I added an example to show what's happening)

Comment: The popup offers you two choices: you need to select one.

Comment: how do I avoid the pop-up and make the eclipse automatically display system.out.println()?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **Type Filters** preference page for this, as you almost never want to refer to anything in the `jdk.internals` packages, and it will apply regardless of the JDK you're using.

[image: Type Filters preference page, with an arrow pointing to the Add Packages button, showing a popup filtering on jdk.internal packages]

Answer (score 0):

See [**Nitin Dahyabhai's answer** for the straightforward and **recommended** solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561757/6505250).

Alternatively, to avoid that the content assist proposes for `syso` also the type `jdk.internal.misc.FileSystemOption`, you can **add** to the **system library** the **access rule *Forbidden* `**/internal/**`** (assuming [*Hide forbidden references* is enabled in *Type Filters*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561757/6505250)):

1. Go to ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path*** tab Libraries
2. Select ***Acceess rules*** which is a sub-node of the *JRE System Library*
3. Click ***Edit...***
4. In the *Type Access Rules* dialog, click ***Add...***
5. In the *Add Access Rules* dialog, enter **`**/internal/**`** click ***OK***
6. In the *Type Access Rules* dialog, click ***OK***
7. Click ***Apply and Close***

[image]

Alternatively, you can change the name of the `sysout` template in the preferences in *Java > Editor > Templates*.

Comment: You wouldn't use the Type Filters for this?

Comment: @nitind Oops, sure, if I had thought of it. Do you like to add that as an answer? Then I will delete my answer.

Comment: It's not like yours is wrong, it's just more work as newew JREs keep coming out.

Comment: @nitind Your answer is more straightforward and what I would recommend when I had thought of it. You are also welcome to copy my answer as an addition to yours when you think that makes sense.

Comment: Just don't delete yours. It might be exactly what someone is looking for later.